# убрать стрелки вверх вниз в select

Tags: html, css

на сайте есть select там всего 2 пункта нужно убрать стрелки вниз вверх [image: select]

Answer (score 3):

Пример

```css
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}

select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="">Option 1</option>
  <option value="">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: странно но не работает http://natali41.beget.tech/

Comment: @Элвин попробуйте почистить кеш

Comment: чистил не помогло

Comment: @Элвин по ссылке вообще ни какого select нету

Answer (score 2):

Вот рабочий пример:
Чтобы избавиться от стрелки в select используйте следующий сss-код:

```css
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<select name="day" id="day" class="day_order">
 <option value="" selected >Все</option>
 <option value="" >Понедельник</option>
</select>
```

Если выполните код то увидите, что все работает. Если нет, то возможно у вас перенастроен браузер с дефолтного состояния, если это например Хром.